# Save a custom Class to a Access Table with VBA

Tags: vba, class, ms-access

I have a really weird one that I'm not quite clear if it's possible. I have an Access database that I've built that stores documents basically. And in it, you are able to produce these documents in Excel. As it stands today, I have it storing values I want to put into a cell as a table value, such as a string. But I'd like to possibly store an attributed string so that I can also store formatting.

I have an idea of how I would make a custom class that would basically be an attributed string, but then I still have the problem that it would need to be an object that could be stored in an Access table.

I was thinking to make an OLEObject field in the table, and save it there, but it gives me an error when I try saving my custom class in that field.

> Run-time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method

I tried making an object variable and then setting my custom class to that, but still same error.

```
Dim attStr As New AttributedStringClass
attStr.Value = "Test Test"

Dim oleObj As Object
Set oleObj = attStr

Dim rst As Recordset: Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTest")
rst.AddNew
rst("attributeString") = oleObj
rst.Update
```

AttributedStringClass

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim zValue As String

Property Get Value() As String
    Value = zValue
End Property

Property Let Value(dValue As String)
    zValue = dValue
End Property
```

I kept it really simple to test if I could store the custom class, just in case it wasn't possible.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For one thing, can't insert an object into OLEObject field same way as with other data types. https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1647315 OLEObject field stores BLOB - object must be converted to bitmap. This conversion is handled by the OLEObject dialog or the methods used in example code. I doubt your idea for a 'custom class' as OLEObject will work because there is no OLEServer associated with your custom class.

Comment: From what I was seeing online, its agreeing with what you are saying. For now I guess I'll toy with the idea of making tables to store the data. Just thought it would be slick if it could store a custom class. Oh well, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by 'attributed' string - bold, italic, color? This is what RichTextFormat is for, requires a Memo field to save in table. RTF is accomplished with HTML tags. An unbound textbox set for RTF can display text formatted with HTML tags as an expression in ControlSource. Excel does not interpret HTML tags. Why involve Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you looking for is object serialization. .net supports serialization, and thus you can convert a object into XML, or these days the much tighter and shorter format used is JSON.

You could however, make your own serializer. So, you would  have to take the custom class you make, and call a routine (passing the class object) to spit out all the values as text. Perhaps the format could be comma delimited, or I suppose even JSON format (but we don't have a good JSON serlizer/de-serlizer like we do in .net).

You then save the text in a standard memo column. You could then read/pull that data, and call a routine to de-serialize the text back into the object.

But, since you do know the class, you can expose each property, and use a for/each loop. this trick is outline here:
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/466141-use-custom-class-each-loop.html

However, what I would simply do  is make your class, add all the "members", and then simply add a routine called serialize, and de serializer.

So:

```
dim clsMyClass     as new clsTour

clsMyClass.HotelName = "Greenwood Inn"
.etc. etc. etc.

' now get all of the values as a string

dim strCsv     as string
strCsv = clsMyClass.Serlize

' now, the comma delimited strCsv as all the values of the class as a string
rstData!Cdata   = strCsv
rstData.update
```

Now, at this point,the memo field is saved (as noted, xml, json, or csv format is fine).

To pull + load (de-serialize) the class, we now go:

```
 dim rstData           as DAO.Recordset
 ' code to load up reocord set
 set rstData = currentdb.OpenRecordSet("Select * from tblTours where id  =2")

 strCsv = rstData!CData
 dim clsMyClass      as new clsTour
 clsMyclass.Serialize = strCsv

 ' at this point, your class is now loaded with all the correct values.
 eg:
 msgbox "Hotel name = " & clsMyClass.HotelName
```

So, in the  .net world, the idea of serializing a class ito a string, passing to a web service, and then on that end, they de-serialize the object back into a class/object.

In .net, this generating is built into the frame work. So, when you call a SOAP or these days more common a REST service, then the data is sent to you as xml (or json). On your end, you now call the de-serialize method, and you have the object now ready for use in your code. So, this idea of converting a class into some kind of "string" or something that can be saved as text, or pass (or pulled) from a web site is rather common these days.

So, your idea and question is rather normal, especially if you coming from any of the modern systems and frameworks that support serialization.

As noted, if your class only has say 5-10 values to save, then a simple method to serialize and de-serialize all values to/from a string from the values the class holds is not hard at all. But for complex objects, then of course one would want a development platform that supports this automatic. In .net, you can pass any object to a serializer, and it will spit back the  xml (or json) string. Now that string can be saved, sent to a web site, or some program. And to get the object, you de-serialize that string back to the object for use in your code.

Do keep in mind that this whole concept only works well for a well defined class, and if the class is not dynamic, then the concept works well.